# How do I change my player name in Titanfall?

Tags: xbox-one, titanfall

I'm playing Titanfall on Xbox one and my name defaulted to SolidRuby#####. How do I change this please? And will changing my name affect my levels gained (I'm still in generation 0)?

Comment: Your name should have defaulted to your gamertag. Is that not your gamertag?

Answer (score 1):

Your player name is your Xbox Live gamertag. Changing your gamertag costs around 10$ (IRRC), but all of your save/progress will be preserved.

You can change your gamertag  [here](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/change-xbox-live-gamertag)

Comment: I am no pro, but to my knowledge, you are allowed to change it once for free if it defaults one for you. Only if it defaults it for you.